# Dynamic panel data with plm. Error "solve.default(Reduce("+", A1)) "

Tags: r, plm

I have a df in `pdata.frame` format from plm library :

`library(plm)`

```
   head(df) :  

       Company Year Kapitalinkomster Bank.o.kassa
3-1920       3 1920         1.388520    0.5520765
3-1921       3 1921         1.251319    0.6952595
3-1922       3 1922         1.001186    0.9812447
3-1923       3 1923         1.056346    1.4212759
3-1924       3 1924         1.451935    0.9596924
3-1925       3 1925         1.435478    0.2283118

dim(df) :
[1] 1196    4


str(df) :
Classes ‘pdata.frame’ and 'data.frame': 1196 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Company         : Factor w/ 42 levels "3","4","5","6",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..- attr(*, "index")='data.frame':    1196 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ Company: Factor w/ 42 levels "3","4","5","6",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. ..$ Year   : Factor w/ 62 levels "1887","1888",..: 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "3-1920" "3-1921" "3-1922" "3-1923" ...
 $ Year            : Factor w/ 62 levels "1887","1888",..: 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 ...
  ..- attr(*, "index")='data.frame':    1196 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. ..$ Company: Factor w/ 42 levels "3","4","5","6",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. ..$ Year   : Factor w/ 62 levels "1887","1888",..: 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "3-1920" "3-1921" "3-1922" "3-1923" ...
 $ Kapitalinkomster:Classes 'pseries', 'numeric'  atomic [1:1196] 1.39 1.25 1 1.06 1.45 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "index")='data.frame': 1196 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Company: Factor w/ 42 levels "3","4","5","6",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. .. ..$ Year   : Factor w/ 62 levels "1887","1888",..: 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 ...
 $ Bank.o.kassa    :Classes 'pseries', 'numeric'  atomic [1:1196] 0.552 0.695 0.981 1.421 0.96 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "index")='data.frame': 1196 obs. of  2 variables:
  .. .. ..$ Company: Factor w/ 42 levels "3","4","5","6",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. .. ..$ Year   : Factor w/ 62 levels "1887","1888",..: 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 ...
 - attr(*, "index")='data.frame':   1196 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ Company: Factor w/ 42 levels "3","4","5","6",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ Year   : Factor w/ 62 levels "1887","1888",..: 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 ...
```

I try to do a two-step dynamic random panel data model,as in plm tutorial pdf on page 23:
[plm vignette](ftp://mirror.cict.fr/cran/web/packages/plm/vignettes/plm.pdf)

```
dynamicrandom=pgmm(Kapitalinkomster~lag(Kapitalinkomster,1)+Bank.o.kassa|lag(Kapitalinkomster,2:99),
                   data=df,effect="twoways",model="twosteps")
```

Then I get this `error` :

```
Error in solve.default(Reduce("+", A1)) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 8.46296e-2

traceback()
3: solve.default(Reduce("+", A1))
2: solve(Reduce("+", A1))
1: pgmm(Kapitalinkomster ~ lag(Kapitalinkomster, 1) + Bank.o.kassa | 
       lag(Kapitalinkomster, 2:99), data = datapd, effect = "individual", 
       model = "twosteps")
```

I find it quite strange.

If I try to run `pgmm` with a smaller data set, where all the "unnecessary" variables are dropped,

```
dim(ph)
[1] 300   4

rownames(ph)=NULL

head(ph)
  Company Year Kapitalinkomster Bank.o.kassa
1       3 1920         1.388520    0.5520765
2       3 1921         1.251319    0.6952595
3       3 1922         1.001186    0.9812447
4       3 1923         1.056346    1.4212759
5       3 1924         1.451935    0.9596924
6       3 1925         1.435478    0.2283118
```

I get the error

```
Error in yX[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
In addition: Warning message:
In `[.data.frame`(index, as.numeric(rownames(mf)), ) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

Does someone has any idea about why `pgmm` is not working for me?

Here is

```
    dput(df[1:60,])
structure(list(Company = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Names = c("3-1920", "3-1921", "3-1922", 
"3-1923", "3-1924", "3-1925", "3-1926", "3-1927", "3-1928", "3-1929", 
"3-1930", "3-1931", "3-1932", "3-1933", "3-1934", "3-1935", "3-1936", 
"4-1887", "4-1888", "4-1889", "4-1890", "4-1891", "4-1892", "4-1893", 
"4-1894", "4-1895", "4-1896", "4-1897", "4-1898", "4-1899", "4-1900", 
"4-1901", "4-1902", "4-1903", "4-1904", "4-1905", "4-1906", "4-1907", 
"4-1908", "4-1909", "4-1910", "4-1911", "4-1912", "4-1913", "4-1914", 
"4-1915", "4-1916", "4-1917", "4-1918", "4-1919", "4-1920", "4-1921", 
"4-1922", "4-1923", "4-1924", "4-1925", "4-1926", "4-1927", "4-1928", 
"4-1929"), .Label = c("3", "4", "5", "6", "10", "12", "14", "19", 
"20", "21", "25", "26", "29", "33", "34", "35", "40", "43", "45", 
"46", "47", "48", "49", "57", "58", "59", "60", "62", "64", "65", 
"68", "69", "71", "72", "73", "74", "76", "77", "79", "80", "83", 
"84"), class = c("pseries", "factor")), Year = structure(c(34L, 
35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 
48L, 49L, 50L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 
38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L), .Names = c("3-1920", "3-1921", 
"3-1922", "3-1923", "3-1924", "3-1925", "3-1926", "3-1927", "3-1928", 
"3-1929", "3-1930", "3-1931", "3-1932", "3-1933", "3-1934", "3-1935", 
"3-1936", "4-1887", "4-1888", "4-1889", "4-1890", "4-1891", "4-1892", 
"4-1893", "4-1894", "4-1895", "4-1896", "4-1897", "4-1898", "4-1899", 
"4-1900", "4-1901", "4-1902", "4-1903", "4-1904", "4-1905", "4-1906", 
"4-1907", "4-1908", "4-1909", "4-1910", "4-1911", "4-1912", "4-1913", 
"4-1914", "4-1915", "4-1916", "4-1917", "4-1918", "4-1919", "4-1920", 
"4-1921", "4-1922", "4-1923", "4-1924", "4-1925", "4-1926", "4-1927", 
"4-1928", "4-1929"), .Label = c("1887", "1888", "1889", "1890", 
"1891", "1892", "1893", "1894", "1895", "1896", "1897", "1898", 
"1899", "1900", "1901", "1902", "1903", "1904", "1905", "1906", 
"1907", "1908", "1909", "1910", "1911", "1912", "1913", "1914", 
"1915", "1916", "1917", "1918", "1919", "1920", "1921", "1922", 
"1923", "1924", "1925", "1926", "1927", "1928", "1929", "1930", 
"1931", "1932", "1933", "1934", "1935", "1936", "1937", "1938", 
"1939", "1940", "1941", "1942", "1943", "1944", "1945", "1946", 
"1947", "1948"), class = c("pseries", "factor")), Kapitalinkomster = structure(c(1.3885195254922, 
1.25131942960191, 1.00118642574671, 1.05634611761787, 1.45193473728394, 
1.43547824494178, 1.38055601480859, 1.34933328550615, 1.28899624736276, 
0.76598077860797, 0.655935113492874, 0.774737637154851, 1.25108435851729, 
1.47671292146985, 1.34370424443801, 1.32632101821461, 1.51421133098558, 
1.26164769097955, 0.955087391528799, 1.12112930644918, 6.97097381553989, 
7.79692376727096, 6.75239407150735, 2.08849093781665, 2.59292961541875, 
3.11050340941574, 2.96014979405135, 5.52806493525727, 4.2921092782187, 
4.6719464983905, 3.83041286491572, 4.07770060833387, 4.25073315665221, 
4.3909964974014, 4.11259760549932, 4.28222569526617, 3.79412435277674, 
4.01135863256581, 4.3810637384393, 4.45988129747339, 4.44638766670966, 
4.09501035463032, 4.71990150360464, 4.67768296668679, 4.4802955128012, 
5.04020000347546, 5.12446555871404, 4.75796798559771, 7.5561386506949, 
4.88420437113848, 4.84541975371883, 5.18996412420159, 5.17554303094439, 
5.39663296271381, 5.61129389005161, 5.33778018090439, 5.49889317435039, 
5.24776724759386, 4.83822195731842, 4.90661955903865), .Names = c("3-1920", 
"3-1921", "3-1922", "3-1923", "3-1924", "3-1925", "3-1926", "3-1927", 
"3-1928", "3-1929", "3-1930", "3-1931", "3-1932", "3-1933", "3-1934", 
"3-1935", "3-1936", "4-1887", "4-1888", "4-1889", "4-1890", "4-1891", 
"4-1892", "4-1893", "4-1894", "4-1895", "4-1896", "4-1897", "4-1898", 
"4-1899", "4-1900", "4-1901", "4-1902", "4-1903", "4-1904", "4-1905", 
"4-1906", "4-1907", "4-1908", "4-1909", "4-1910", "4-1911", "4-1912", 
"4-1913", "4-1914", "4-1915", "4-1916", "4-1917", "4-1918", "4-1919", 
"4-1920", "4-1921", "4-1922", "4-1923", "4-1924", "4-1925", "4-1926", 
"4-1927", "4-1928", "4-1929")), Aktiebolag = structure(c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), .Names = c("3-1920", 
"3-1921", "3-1922", "3-1923", "3-1924", "3-1925", "3-1926", "3-1927", 
"3-1928", "3-1929", "3-1930", "3-1931", "3-1932", "3-1933", "3-1934", 
"3-1935", "3-1936", "4-1887", "4-1888", "4-1889", "4-1890", "4-1891", 
"4-1892", "4-1893", "4-1894", "4-1895", "4-1896", "4-1897", "4-1898", 
"4-1899", "4-1900", "4-1901", "4-1902", "4-1903", "4-1904", "4-1905", 
"4-1906", "4-1907", "4-1908", "4-1909", "4-1910", "4-1911", "4-1912", 
"4-1913", "4-1914", "4-1915", "4-1916", "4-1917", "4-1918", "4-1919", 
"4-1920", "4-1921", "4-1922", "4-1923", "4-1924", "4-1925", "4-1926", 
"4-1927", "4-1928", "4-1929")), Bank.o.kassa = structure(c(0.552076466710613, 
0.695259455479398, 0.981244655715202, 1.42127589620433, 0.959692448821232, 
0.228311793009368, 0.30871924158571, 2.69943145432275, 3.04368302717424, 
3.05290552372935, 4.24442587875512, 2.43324032807521, 4.69502073549705, 
4.21425554491043, 3.43802415683905, 1.91228479124126, 0.183612711919672, 
1.93873324222939, 0.658324934241255, 1.65583430229754, 8.16610788753491, 
10.6696930067877, 6.20505938433427, 0.768959064173528, 2.47147653520727, 
1.4749677888885, 2.1905085760638, 10.4511636424978, 18.4910241070292, 
15.5739616534392, 11.4808752327392, 7.18593926102981, 4.79510448317011, 
2.85703955642673, 1.82405600468293, 1.14336459853929, 1.91224006506971, 
1.86664771087767, 3.29991106032535, 3.01042462888444, 6.84688859551067, 
4.5949838689742, 4.95776617931262, 6.01761059832527, 5.12621851069932, 
2.36515966545918, 2.50574176281981, 1.88913570646181, 2.12361708504312, 
1.70295644658185, 0.237788523257187, 3.94594260772663, 0.514660379058555, 
0.63723501085728, 0.163482237867645, 0.197324873476979, 0.692618649628274, 
0.316872042668265, 1.67508648494876, 0.142354356664425), .Names = c("3-1920", 
"3-1921", "3-1922", "3-1923", "3-1924", "3-1925", "3-1926", "3-1927", 
"3-1928", "3-1929", "3-1930", "3-1931", "3-1932", "3-1933", "3-1934", 
"3-1935", "3-1936", "4-1887", "4-1888", "4-1889", "4-1890", "4-1891", 
"4-1892", "4-1893", "4-1894", "4-1895", "4-1896", "4-1897", "4-1898", 
"4-1899", "4-1900", "4-1901", "4-1902", "4-1903", "4-1904", "4-1905", 
"4-1906", "4-1907", "4-1908", "4-1909", "4-1910", "4-1911", "4-1912", 
"4-1913", "4-1914", "4-1915", "4-1916", "4-1917", "4-1918", "4-1919", 
"4-1920", "4-1921", "4-1922", "4-1923", "4-1924", "4-1925", "4-1926", 
"4-1927", "4-1928", "4-1929")), Obligationer = structure(c(0, 
0.710619775236431, 0.569764858043086, 0.663694337104649, 0.761033448298168, 
0.319840031930296, 0.312307395488807, 0.0346835018362475, 0.0330125633514856, 
0.0188647549138383, 0.0151764700315497, 0.018196428174861, 0.0300829419881919, 
9.20824963171287, 8.09476461975424, 7.33591599214263, 10.3237519153303, 
23.4587496564246, 8.34307628014455, 8.21105338961859, 19.3630967796124, 
18.5571303656964, 26.520466175308, 7.10867944326549, 6.98218342383004, 
6.27961874258339, 5.04505474511001, 6.80023508002221, 8.77338607338471, 
8.86362404959709, 7.75977758606352, 10.3435727294857, 9.89547857880742, 
9.53223792314849, 11.9082814125304, 12.8046506505709, 15.1592108784811, 
15.398922387006, 15.1136243789378, 14.6794808956586, 14.2827955517189, 
14.7029129176851, 15.5305565249781, 14.9495702592336, 13.5321062823358, 
16.9791185495982, 27.5452432427652, 35.5636383102538, 31.5779522681227, 
31.3394353672748, 38.0906430075851, 39.4360188809573, 40.2139304909776, 
40.592971239732, 37.6076781083026, 34.5895784054617, 31.8919927541514, 
29.1162189615666, 26.8061925543101, 27.0963897344843), .Names = c("3-1920", 
"3-1921", "3-1922", "3-1923", "3-1924", "3-1925", "3-1926", "3-1927", 
"3-1928", "3-1929", "3-1930", "3-1931", "3-1932", "3-1933", "3-1934", 
"3-1935", "3-1936", "4-1887", "4-1888", "4-1889", "4-1890", "4-1891", 
"4-1892", "4-1893", "4-1894", "4-1895", "4-1896", "4-1897", "4-1898", 
"4-1899", "4-1900", "4-1901", "4-1902", "4-1903", "4-1904", "4-1905", 
"4-1906", "4-1907", "4-1908", "4-1909", "4-1910", "4-1911", "4-1912", 
"4-1913", "4-1914", "4-1915", "4-1916", "4-1917", "4-1918", "4-1919", 
"4-1920", "4-1921", "4-1922", "4-1923", "4-1924", "4-1925", "4-1926", 
"4-1927", "4-1928", "4-1929")), Lån = structure(c(21.8552046760463, 
16.9354631519048, 14.1079257359718, 16.7908540878211, 21.8125358015014, 
22.7049393024745, 22.9845270523343, 20.6327272995821, 20.2367766482934, 
9.0730433268189, 8.76280146788203, 8.45831605254012, 18.5583384882304, 
16.0227874442418, 14.4469141085505, 16.2948078954055, 18.4678621483242, 
34.8801647613554, 12.8718995058876, 26.2903301206017, 64.6032084887766, 
61.4639536152419, 57.7399633611202, 24.4863080781916, 27.8232438432077, 
30.3833412076318, 30.0677530506136, 65.1444741565493, 56.6516443429197, 
60.315684852254, 56.4199996064144, 60.1715597365204, 65.0667857507308, 
69.0349764486106, 66.422363861315, 67.6453246293749, 65.7992995302202, 
65.8377134866222, 70.3265356626504, 71.1633761722355, 67.0366584836927, 
68.6845898885332, 69.184192353293, 68.9082294008192, 67.774846884622, 
75.1563302426472, 63.307097388227, 55.885346238016, 56.7374120385912, 
56.4914905969678, 52.7731271340091, 48.12682459542, 49.3502034782439, 
49.1867624617933, 52.8503985776916, 55.3039715920661, 57.9145523998424, 
60.7339335739289, 59.9731465741533, 49.3913672299458), .Names = c("3-1920", 
"3-1921", "3-1922", "3-1923", "3-1924", "3-1925", "3-1926", "3-1927", 
"3-1928", "3-1929", "3-1930", "3-1931", "3-1932", "3-1933", "3-1934", 
"3-1935", "3-1936", "4-1887", "4-1888", "4-1889", "4-1890", "4-1891", 
"4-1892", "4-1893", "4-1894", "4-1895", "4-1896", "4-1897", "4-1898", 
"4-1899", "4-1900", "4-1901", "4-1902", "4-1903", "4-1904", "4-1905", 
"4-1906", "4-1907", "4-1908", "4-1909", "4-1910", "4-1911", "4-1912", 
"4-1913", "4-1914", "4-1915", "4-1916", "4-1917", "4-1918", "4-1919", 
"4-1920", "4-1921", "4-1922", "4-1923", "4-1924", "4-1925", "4-1926", 
"4-1927", "4-1928", "4-1929")), Aktier = structure(c(3.07318204837309, 
2.07446311309404, 1.43295861797836, 0.510917006044213, 0.585849402603378, 
0.565762106856816, 0.276425856457835, 0.264148494973398, 0.251422678300478, 
58.0164377288786, 15.2785505467049, 52.7552822254383, 3.38621830653397, 
3.04972648885867, 0.847461182502024, 3.72584362278638, 0.214291913995251, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.880242370615362, 0.782706137309241, 0.690115718443861, 
0.800097690345683, 1.06271791918577, 0.834468719186235, 0.0962303485314691, 
0.0884637193545766, 0.084862230936858, 0.0802494456090769, 0.0744384419445548, 
0.07795889974169, 0.0732881714498627, 0.064264352555926, 12.4266612039723
), .Names = c("3-1920", "3-1921", "3-1922", "3-1923", "3-1924", 
"3-1925", "3-1926", "3-1927", "3-1928", "3-1929", "3-1930", "3-1931", 
"3-1932", "3-1933", "3-1934", "3-1935", "3-1936", "4-1887", "4-1888", 
"4-1889", "4-1890", "4-1891", "4-1892", "4-1893", "4-1894", "4-1895", 
"4-1896", "4-1897", "4-1898", "4-1899", "4-1900", "4-1901", "4-1902", 
"4-1903", "4-1904", "4-1905", "4-1906", "4-1907", "4-1908", "4-1909", 
"4-1910", "4-1911", "4-1912", "4-1913", "4-1914", "4-1915", "4-1916", 
"4-1917", "4-1918", "4-1919", "4-1920", "4-1921", "4-1922", "4-1923", 
"4-1924", "4-1925", "4-1926", "4-1927", "4-1928", "4-1929")), 
    Placeringar.andra.ftg = structure(c(28.0431221549195, 25.9545126815565, 
    24.0242448095517, 31.3234881936435, 39.255978576323, 42.1621242692298, 
    43.6032738316212, 45.4357566594961, 46.598249907364, 28.4981460177937, 
    17.0504236197116, 23.836948841527, 48.4988040028843, 45.556077510276, 
    38.8496679378584, 38.6176234980822, 38.9963029248996, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.74742599118763, 0.952114597368105, 
    0.911108175078138, 2.15433130730393, 2.22837176822736, 1.6965099678165, 
    2.01166483245572, 1.92960283356866, 1.89400279726231, 1.83065143079271, 
    1.8441365039718, 1.74778438036979, 1.70553412657279, 1.74014123634787, 
    1.57422476543071), .Names = c("3-1920", "3-1921", "3-1922", 
    "3-1923", "3-1924", "3-1925", "3-1926", "3-1927", "3-1928", 
    "3-1929", "3-1930", "3-1931", "3-1932", "3-1933", "3-1934", 
    "3-1935", "3-1936", "4-1887", "4-1888", "4-1889", "4-1890", 
    "4-1891", "4-1892", "4-1893", "4-1894", "4-1895", "4-1896", 
    "4-1897", "4-1898", "4-1899", "4-1900", "4-1901", "4-1902", 
    "4-1903", "4-1904", "4-1905", "4-1906", "4-1907", "4-1908", 
    "4-1909", "4-1910", "4-1911", "4-1912", "4-1913", "4-1914", 
    "4-1915", "4-1916", "4-1917", "4-1918", "4-1919", "4-1920", 
    "4-1921", "4-1922", "4-1923", "4-1924", "4-1925", "4-1926", 
    "4-1927", "4-1928", "4-1929")), Fodringar = structure(c(13.4091880009393, 
    11.4007737009461, 8.85180109245837, 10.5207294715513, 11.8554668691406, 
    11.6406790162891, 10.8301249257183, 10.5342894550549, 10.2725808443785, 
    0.0712700398569951, 19.6151778087924, 4.08751075071719, 8.5369441404377, 
    7.22244542654346, 5.74211168867129, 5.00624411086692, 5.70750325407667, 
    11.7113734113266, 21.5391725460311, 17.601114228451, 3.05187896774013, 
    5.56912149567179, 5.47086167639443, 15.6851978435924, 14.9119890182211, 
    15.0092045884117, 12.6228928396926, 0.442201848780838, 0.662413501667926, 
    0.849732956673642, 1.47202590554835, 1.56431397609731, 1.65711491625151, 
    1.7323412708195, 1.85220571392917, 1.93390958786632, 1.84134615133785, 
    1.99887445786696, 1.83728108674151, 2.46597909355305, 3.73562846025962, 
    3.76713685012398, 1.96943185869625, 2.29567819454465, 2.17585138923596, 
    3.4385473363555, 4.04443383630046, 4.4787124078019, 5.91953337740812, 
    6.7714060177497, 1.06707862774494, 1.14746124710284, 1.05345153517615, 
    0.952153564360688, 0.945755278051777, 1.05282199902918, 1.32354993575186, 
    1.31741363057881, 1.29531376381482, 2.49542755736025), .Names = c("3-1920", 
    "3-1921", "3-1922", "3-1923", "3-1924", "3-1925", "3-1926", 
    "3-1927", "3-1928", "3-1929", "3-1930", "3-1931", "3-1932", 
    "3-1933", "3-1934", "3-1935", "3-1936", "4-1887", "4-1888", 
    "4-1889", "4-1890", "4-1891", "4-1892", "4-1893", "4-1894", 
    "4-1895", "4-1896", "4-1897", "4-1898", "4-1899", "4-1900", 
    "4-1901", "4-1902", "4-1903", "4-1904", "4-1905", "4-1906", 
    "4-1907", "4-1908", "4-1909", "4-1910", "4-1911", "4-1912", 
    "4-1913", "4-1914", "4-1915", "4-1916", "4-1917", "4-1918", 
    "4-1919", "4-1920", "4-1921", "4-1922", "4-1923", "4-1924", 
    "4-1925", "4-1926", "4-1927", "4-1928", "4-1929")), Reala.tillgångar = structure(c(24.1236303297959, 
    37.4986675879214, 46.6429235423771, 35.4664214060824, 21.107906639929, 
    19.0801609856783, 18.4927931928856, 17.5395655673799, 17.1966584758689, 
    0, 34.7674001114172, 7.96457079858135, 15.6705819482217, 
    14.1133809273624, 28.0736200437156, 26.5998804921383, 25.6518212731437, 
    1.95963811345151, 56.5875267336955, 46.2416679590312, 0.482603187490813, 
    0.398935965859933, 0.307217480627311, 51.950855570777, 47.8111071795339, 
    46.8528676724846, 50.0737907885199, 15.4355247525754, 14.2093849840859, 
    13.3958115562226, 22.7149659643704, 20.7346142968668, 18.5855162710402, 
    16.8434048009947, 17.9930930075424, 16.4727505336486, 15.2879033748912, 
    14.8978419576271, 9.42264781134492, 8.68073920966838, 8.09802890881811, 
    8.2503764746835, 8.35805308372005, 7.82891154707734, 11.1718677682141, 
    0.0111751265820557, 0.00993685427215673, 0.00876137160323813, 
    0.009999421233499, 0.0321994407601129, 5.19895399696667, 
    5.06909968623497, 5.74993956248165, 5.65223190455595, 5.47608036625753, 
    5.80844475706357, 5.67763062110834, 5.30082678935982, 6.52809468404085, 
    6.31727899750595), .Names = c("3-1920", "3-1921", "3-1922", 
    "3-1923", "3-1924", "3-1925", "3-1926", "3-1927", "3-1928", 
    "3-1929", "3-1930", "3-1931", "3-1932", "3-1933", "3-1934", 
    "3-1935", "3-1936", "4-1887", "4-1888", "4-1889", "4-1890", 
    "4-1891", "4-1892", "4-1893", "4-1894", "4-1895", "4-1896", 
    "4-1897", "4-1898", "4-1899", "4-1900", "4-1901", "4-1902", 
    "4-1903", "4-1904", "4-1905", "4-1906", "4-1907", "4-1908", 
    "4-1909", "4-1910", "4-1911", "4-1912", "4-1913", "4-1914", 
    "4-1915", "4-1916", "4-1917", "4-1918", "4-1919", "4-1920", 
    "4-1921", "4-1922", "4-1923", "4-1924", "4-1925", "4-1926", 
    "4-1927", "4-1928", "4-1929")), Övriga.tillgångar = structure(c(8.94359632321529, 
    4.73024053386131, 3.38913668790429, 3.30261960154855, 3.66153681338318, 
    3.29818249453177, 3.19182850390819, 2.85939756735457, 2.36761585526891, 
    1.26933260800861, 0.266044096705159, 0.445934574945972, 0.624009436206777, 
    0.613077026094302, 0.507436262108836, 0.507399597336736, 
    0.454853858310495, 26.0513408152126, 0, 0, 4.33310468884518, 
    3.34116555074217, 3.75643192221575, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.72640051957453, 
    1.21214699091261, 1.00118493181342, 0.152355704864146, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.219109164892739, 0.422000717554878, 
    0.852726180937993, 0.573182072341244, 0.677056811951724, 
    0.371422443252653, 0.101430023434196, 0.166757801571104, 
    1.09974800113887, 0.999780790501637, 1.04570455542704, 1.12928342698615, 
    0.673912359406274, 1.43591270387502, 1.91776034982839, 0.556296154636263
    ), .Names = c("3-1920", "3-1921", "3-1922", "3-1923", "3-1924", 
    "3-1925", "3-1926", "3-1927", "3-1928", "3-1929", "3-1930", 
    "3-1931", "3-1932", "3-1933", "3-1934", "3-1935", "3-1936", 
    "4-1887", "4-1888", "4-1889", "4-1890", "4-1891", "4-1892", 
    "4-1893", "4-1894", "4-1895", "4-1896", "4-1897", "4-1898", 
    "4-1899", "4-1900", "4-1901", "4-1902", "4-1903", "4-1904", 
    "4-1905", "4-1906", "4-1907", "4-1908", "4-1909", "4-1910", 
    "4-1911", "4-1912", "4-1913", "4-1914", "4-1915", "4-1916", 
    "4-1917", "4-1918", "4-1919", "4-1920", "4-1921", "4-1922", 
    "4-1923", "4-1924", "4-1925", "4-1926", "4-1927", "4-1928", 
    "4-1929"))), .Names = c("Company", "Year", "Kapitalinkomster", 
"Aktiebolag", "Bank.o.kassa", "Obligationer", "Lån", "Aktier", 
"Placeringar.andra.ftg", "Fodringar", "Reala.tillgångar", "Övriga.tillgångar"
), index = structure(list(Company = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("3", "4"), class = "factor"), 
    Year = structure(c(34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 
    42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
    17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
    29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 
    41L, 42L, 43L), .Label = c("1887", "1888", "1889", "1890", 
    "1891", "1892", "1893", "1894", "1895", "1896", "1897", "1898", 
    "1899", "1900", "1901", "1902", "1903", "1904", "1905", "1906", 
    "1907", "1908", "1909", "1910", "1911", "1912", "1913", "1914", 
    "1915", "1916", "1917", "1918", "1919", "1920", "1921", "1922", 
    "1923", "1924", "1925", "1926", "1927", "1928", "1929", "1930", 
    "1931", "1932", "1933", "1934", "1935", "1936"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Company", 
"Year"), row.names = c(NA, -60L), class = "data.frame"), row.names = c("3-1920", 
"3-1921", "3-1922", "3-1923", "3-1924", "3-1925", "3-1926", "3-1927", 
"3-1928", "3-1929", "3-1930", "3-1931", "3-1932", "3-1933", "3-1934", 
"3-1935", "3-1936", "4-1887", "4-1888", "4-1889", "4-1890", "4-1891", 
"4-1892", "4-1893", "4-1894", "4-1895", "4-1896", "4-1897", "4-1898", 
"4-1899", "4-1900", "4-1901", "4-1902", "4-1903", "4-1904", "4-1905", 
"4-1906", "4-1907", "4-1908", "4-1909", "4-1910", "4-1911", "4-1912", 
"4-1913", "4-1914", "4-1915", "4-1916", "4-1917", "4-1918", "4-1919", 
"4-1920", "4-1921", "4-1922", "4-1923", "4-1924", "4-1925", "4-1926", 
"4-1927", "4-1928", "4-1929"), class = c("pdata.frame", "data.frame"
))
```

Best Regards

Comment: If you could paste the output from `dput(df)`, that information might help others to reproduce and analyze your problem.

Comment: dput(df) is veery long, could maybe str(df) help?

Comment: Try running your model on `data=df[1:100,]`, and see if you can generate the same error. Try and make the smallest dataset you can in which you can reproduce the problem, and then post the dataset. You could also try posting your `traceback()` after you run the model.

Comment: If I run on `data=df[1:100,]` I get error: `Error in model.frame.default(terms(formula, lhs = lhs, rhs = rhs, data = data),  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'lag(Kapitalinkomster, 1)')`

Comment: Yes, try bigger datasets until you can reproduce the error. Reduce your dataset by removing all the unnecessary columns, and the unnecessary row names.

Comment: @nograpes ok thanks! I will try it the first thing tomorrow when I have access to R again. I seem not to be the first one to get that error though...´´http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Running-a-GMM-Estimation-on-dynamic-Panel-Model-using-plm-Package-td3592466.html

Comment: @nograpes I now added `traceback ()` and tried with smaller data sets... See the edited output above. Any suggestions? Best Regards

Comment: You have to make the problem reproducible for anybody to help you. The purpose of making the data small is so that you could post it here. I noticed that your full dataset only has 1196 variables. Perhaps you can still post it with `dput(df)`, so we can cut and paste it into our browsers. If it is too big, post the smaller dataset. The `str(df)` is unhelpful.

Comment: @nograpes Of course, dput is posted for the 60 first lines. If I use STATA I get quiet the same error `Warning: Two-step estimated covariance matrix of moments is singular.
  Using a generalized inverse to calculate optimal weighting matrix for two-step estimation`. But STATA seems to be able to solve it. I want to understand what the error steems from...

Comment: @user1665355 Perhaps it is better to ask this kind of question in Cross Validated, where they can help you with the statistics. It appears that R is working correctly, and telling you that the system is `computationally singular`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you include all of the lags `|lag(Kapitalinkomster,2:99)` you make instrument matrix too big. This results in matrices of deficient rank. This is evident looking at the general GMM formula for linear panel models. For example page 190 in Chapter 8 of "Econometric analysis of cross section and panel data" by J. M. Wooldridge. The simple (and incorrect) explanation is that by including too many lags you get more columns than rows. Try reducing the number of lags in the `|lag(Kapitalinkomster,2:99)`, use two, or three at most.